# Normalize a variable (divide by its total)

Tags: sas

I have a variable of weight, *wprm*, that takes integer values. I would like to have one that is the weight "normalized", that is to say *wprm*/*sum(wprm)*

I can do that by outputing a `proc summary` ant then a `merge` to put it back with the original data, and then dividing my *wprm* variable, but it seems a bit heavy, is there a simpler way ?

Comment: Proc STDIZE or STANDARD - various methods to normalize data.

Comment: I'm a bit curious why you think it's heavy.  PROC MEANS/SUMMARY is quite fast in most cases, and is one of the better ways to do this (though agree that PROC STDIZE is better for your particular case).

Comment: Maybe heavy was an overstatement. It was rather a matter of simplification of my code, plus of personal curiosity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PROC STDIZE or PROC STANDARD - they both allow various normalization methods.

```
proc stdize data=have method=sum out=want;
var wprm;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the macro `%simple_normalize` from [here](https://github.com/FinancialRiskGroup/SASPerformanceAnalytics/blob/master/Performance%20Analytics%20Library/macro/simple_normalize.sas).

```
data test;
  do i=1 to 10;
     output;
  end;
run;

%simple_normalize(test,i);
```

Comment: I would not recommend this macro.  It is never a good idea to convert a numeric to character for any purpose other than display.

Comment: with 32 digits, you are covering all the precision available.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64

Comment: Perhaps most of the time it is adequate but I would not count on BEST32. Conversion to character and back to numeric for no good reason seems a bit naive.

Comment: No, it is adequate 100% of the time with a double precision number.

Answer (score 0):

The other common option is SQL, but it will post a warning/note to the log that many people don't like.

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select a.*, a.wprm/sum(a.wprm) as weight
from have;
quit;
```